# How does AWS Cloudfront cost work for requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

After reading the documentation on AWS Cloudfront, I am aware that there is a cost for every 10,000 requests (either HTTP or HTTPS).

I was curious about whether the cost applies to all requests on Cloudfront including those files that are cached or does it apply only apply to requests for invalidating current cached files?

I am guessing it's the first option, but I wanted to know just to be in case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/) page indicates the request pricing for *all* HTTP/HTTPS methods per 10,000 requests (which will include both content fetch and invalidation requests). Note that HTTPS requests cost more.

Invalidation requests themselves have an additional cost, after the first 1,000 per month.

Answer (score 0):

This applies to all requests including the ones that are hitting the cache.